# html2canvas OnRender failed because of cross domain images

Tags: php, html, html2canvas

I want a screenshot of the current page through html2canvas. However, the code displays "here" and then stops the second alert function is not triggering

```
alert("here");
html2canvas(instance.element, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        alert("here");
        instance.options.onPostRender(canvas)
```

In the firebug the following error appears:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://html2canvas.appspot.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.otherdomain.com%2Flivezilla%2Fimage.php%3Fid%3D08&callback=html2canvas_1"
```

I think its because the image is from another domain, but I did not find any solution.

Comment: Try this: http://html2canvas.appspot.com/query?callback=?&xhr2=false&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F

Answer (score 3):

I think you need a proxy in order to use cross-browser images.
html2canvas allows you to use a proxy on it's settings:

```
html2canvas(instance.element, {
proxy: 'yourProxyPageOnTheSameServer.php',
onrendered: function(canvas) {
    alert("here");
    instance.options.onPostRender(canvas)
```

and there's a proxy in php here:
https://github.com/brcontainer/html2canvas-php-proxy