# div to image to download

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have problem puting div in the image. The thing is that I want to make div as downloadable (right click, download as image OR on button). This is my div which i want to be "downloadable"

```
<div style="display: block; background-color: transparent; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(&quot;images/fujairah-plates.png&quot;); background-size: contain; min-height: 90px;" class="" id="plate">      
          <div id="plate2"></div>             
          <div class="letter-left draw_code" id="draw_code">&nbsp;B</div>
          <div class="letter-right draw_num" id="draw_num">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

I hope for some constructive suggestions.

Comment: How looks like a 'downloadable' DIV? Could you explain better your expected behaviour? You want to download relevant DIV HTML or what???

Comment: 1st thing is how to tell browser that content of div is downloadable as image

Comment: You could render HTML content into canvas but with some limitations regarding specific properties support. Here is an example using HTML2Canvas plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/fMeRC/1/

Comment: image still dont get rendered... i dont know why http://jsfiddle.net/fMeRC/296/

Comment: That's part of limitation(s). Canvas are subject to cross domain origin policy. You could proxify it server side your images so they have same domain as your page or if your own images from different server, enable CORS. Read that for some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18474727/canvas-has-been-tainted-by-cross-origin-data-work-around

Comment: well, i fixed problem with changing line 350 to topPos = isNaN(parseInt(bgposition[1], 10)) ? topPos : parseInt(bgposition[1], 10);

Comment: Which line are you talking about???

Comment: Ok i see, you are referring to this fix: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/265  But that's still has nothing to do with cross domain images (as i understand it). So be aware of it. EDIT: just find it, i wasn't aware about it, would help i guess in these cases: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17114236/html2canvas-onrender-failed-because-of-cross-domain-images

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML2Canvas JS library to convert the HTML into a canvas and after that, you can export the canvas to data URI using the toDataURI() JavaScript function. That data URI string can be then presented as a downloadable image.
P. S: I've tried it and it works perfectly. ☺